# Suggested way to deploy Moss 2007 custom solutions in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, 2007, migration, solution-package

I am working on Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2010 Migration. We have a custom master page deployed as feature. We are using database attach-detach method for migration.

1. How do I deploy custom solutions in Moss 2007 to SharePoint 2010. What are different possible ways.

2. we got a upgradelog and we have few 2 missingfiles and 2 missingfeatures, they belong to above mentioned custom master page. How do I deal with these. I read that we can delete these using powershell scripts. Wanted to check if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom solution packaged as a WSP? If yes, then you can just deploy the WSP on SP 2010.

If not, then you need to manually deploy all the files and DLL's. 
For DLL's - extract from GAC i.e. Follow the following steps to copy DLL from GAC

1. Run `regsvr32 /u C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\shfusion.dll`
2. `shfusion.dll` is an explorer extension DLL that gives a distinct look to the GAC folder. Un-registering this file will remove the assembly cache viewer and the GAC folder will be then visible as any normal folder in explorer.
3. Open `“%windir%\assembly\GAC_MSIL”`.
4. Browse to your DLL folder into the deep to find your DLL.
5. Copy the DLL somewhere on your hard disk
6. Run `"regsvr32 /i %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.NET version directory> \shfusion.dll"` to re-register the `shfusion.dll` file and regain the original distinct view of the GAC.
7. Use `gacutil /i <DLL path>` to deploy the DLLs on the SP 2010 servers. 
   Copy other ASCX and ASPX files and move them into appropriate folders inside the 14 hive on SP 2010 servers.

But the best way would be to create SharePoint project files using VS 2010 etc. and create a WSP package.